# How to read a value append it to 2nd line and then append the 2nd line to third line ,

Tags: loops, awk

I have around 100 cells in a file so i need to read the name of the file and append the file name to "pin" then read the second line and append it to the third lines "direction" so what is the way to do it

example

```
MACRO x1
PIN low {
DIRECTION INPUT ;
PIN high {
DIRECTION INPUT ;


MACRO  u1
PIN S1 {
DIRECTION INPUT ;
PIN S2 {
DIRECTION INOUT ;
```

what i need as output

```
MACRO x1
x1 PIN low
x1 PIN low DIRECTION INPUT ;
x1 PIN low
x1 PIN low DIRECTION INPUT ;

MACRO u1
u1 PIN S1
u1 PIN S1 DIRECTION INPUT ;
u1 PIN S2
u1 PIN S2 DIRECTION INOUT ;
```

Comment: also, the code you tried doesn't make sense with the sample input posted.. there is no `cell` in the sample input but code is using it

Comment: sorry its macro

Comment: I had changed some things earlier also  but did not explain sir ,so now its a different one i have posted see if you can teach me how to get it done please

Comment: you'll need to better formulate your question... think before posting.. add all details (for ex: why is `{` not present in expected output)... add your own efforts to solve the question(you cannot simply ask for free code)...

Comment: i do not want { in my output and from 2 days i am trying i am not able to get it so i have posted it sir

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '
/MACRO/{                           ##Looking for string MACRO here and if that is found then do following actions:
  val=$2;                          ##Creating a variable named val whose value is the 2nd field of the current line.
  flag=1;                          ##Creating a variable named flag here and setting its value to 1 here.
  print;                           ##Print is the out of the box keyword for awk and it will print the current line.
  next                             ##next is awk out of the box command which will skip all further statements.
}
flag && !/DIRECTION INPUT/ && NF{  ##Checking condition here if variable flag is NOT NULL and line is NOT having string DIRECTION INPUT in it and line is NOT blank:
  sub(/{/,"");                     ##Substituting character { with NULL on current line.
  val2=$0;                         ##Creating variable named val2 with value of current line.
  print val,$0                     ##Printing the value of variable val along with current line.
}
/DIRECTION INPUT/{                 ##Checking if current line is having string DIRECTION INPUT in it, if yes then do following:
  print val,val2,$0                ##Printing variable named val, val2 and current line here.
}
' Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
MACRO XYZ
XYZ PIN AB
XYZ PIN AB  DIRECTION INPUT ;
XYZ PIN BC
XYZ PIN BC  DIRECTION INPUT ;
MACRO  GEN
GEN PIN DECSEL_STG2[0]
GEN PIN DECSEL_STG2[0]  DIRECTION INPUT ;
GEN PIN DECSEL_STG1[0]
GEN PIN DECSEL_STG1[0]  DIRECTION INPUT ;
```

Comment: can you explain it in detail please ,can it be done using loops

Comment: @akshaysiddamal, I haven't see it but this post seems to be marked as duplicate thread now :(

Comment: ok sir , if you get let me know please i need it

Comment: now i have changed it out, how can i do it sir

Comment: @akshaysiddamal, add explanation now, please try to learn from it and share your learning too.